# Why wouldn't the code work in the for loop?

Tags: java

Homework problem got the first 4 questions got stuck on this last one. If the user inputted hello as the string and 3 as the integer it's supposed to print "helheh" when I try it prints "helhehehehehe"

Question:Write a program that reads a string and an integer, n, from the user. Output a string made of the first n characters of the string, followed by the first n-1 characters of the string, and so on. You may assume that n is between 0 and the length of the string, inclusive.

I tried having it add to the string with i-1 in the substring section but that didn't work.

```
 System.out.println("Please input a string: ");
 string = in.next();

 System.out.println("Please input an integer: ");
 n = in.nextInt();

 int lenstring = string.length();

 String tring = string.substring(0,n);
 for(int i = lenstring; i>0; i--)
 {
     con += string.substring(0,n-1);
 }
System.out.println(tring+con);
```

Comment: Where is the variable `con` declared? Nvm `tring` I found it mistake.

Comment: @Goion Just before the loop.

Comment: What is the actual goal here? I'm not totally clear on why `hello` and `3` should result in `helheh`.

Comment: @Goion it said to add the relevant code I thought it could be assumed that all variables were initialized and declared.

Comment: @mypetlionI just edited sorry for the inconvinience

Comment: I am just covering my basis.

Comment: `con += string.substring(0,n-1);` isn't the variable defined in your for-loop called `i`? Shouldn't it be `i-1` instead of `n-1`?

Comment: Within the `for` loop, you are counting backwards from `n` to `1`, which is fine. You are, however, not using the counter variable (`i`). Try to replace `.substring(0, n - 1)` with `.substring(0, i)`.

Comment: @MCEmperor that would output "helhellohellhelheh" I don't understand why it printed it that much.

Comment: To add to MC Emperor, I think to solve your exercise, you'd also want to initialize `i=n`

Comment: @ds08 Well, you also need to initialize `tring` to `""` (empty string).

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this:

```
for( int i = n;  i > 0;  i-- )
   con += string.substring( 0, i );
System.out.println( con );
```

I have not tried it, but I believe it should work.

In any case, if you just think about it, it may help you understand what you need to do and why you need to do it this way and not some other way.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the for statement with

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{ 
     con += string.substring(0,n-i);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I think I understand my issue now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want first characters of a string, the first argument to `substring` must be 0. It is. Check.

If you want n, n-1, ... 1 characters of a string, the second argument to `substring` must be n, n-1, ... 1. In your loop, it obviously not. Your loop should be from n to 1 (or 0, but concatenating an empty string makes no sense).

Answer (score 0):

you could use the  `n` for the loop

```
    System.out.println("Please input a string: ");
    String string = in.next();

    System.out.println("Please input an integer: ");
    int n = in.nextInt();

    String con = "";
    String tring = string.substring(0,n);
    for(; n>0; n--)
    {
        con += string.substring(0,n-1);
    }
    System.out.println(tring+con);
```